# Passing Dynamic arguments to a function

Tags: php, arguments, user-defined-functions

I have a user defined function below:

```
function char_replace($line1){
    $line1= str_ireplace("Snippet:", "", $line1);
    // First, replace UTF-8 characters.
    $line1= str_replace(
    array("\xe2\x80\x98", "\xe2\x80\x99", "\xe2\x80\x9c", "\xe2\x80\x9d", "\xe2\x80\x93", "\xe2\x80\x94", "\xe2\x80\xa6"),
    array("'", "'", '"', '"', '-', '--', '...'),
    $line1);
    // Next, replace their Windows-1252 equivalents.
    $line1= str_replace(
    array(chr(145), chr(146), chr(147), chr(148), chr(150), chr(151), chr(133)),
    array("'", "'", '"', '"', '-', '--', '...'),
    $line1);
}
```

and i'm replacing characters on multiple lines that i've exploded, except i want to apply a dynamic argument to the function char_replace where `$line` could very well be `$line2` or `$line3` so i would convert the characters this way:
`$line1 = char_replace($line1)`

I want to make the function arguments and the str_replace/str_ireplace arguments to be a dynamic variable, where i could just convert another line like so:
`$random_line = char_replace($random_line)`
Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you end your function with `return $line1;` you can call it like this:

```
$line1 = char_replace($line1);
$line2 = char_replace($line2);
$line3 = char_replace($line3);
```

How you call the arguments in your function definition doesn't matter, they're local to that function and can have a different name outside of it.

Comment: Thanks, all of the answers were similar and they all worked, but i want to know for learning purposes why does adding `return` allow it to be 'dynamic'?

Comment: A function defines an isolated context in which code is run; the function arguments define the input to your function (they can be used as local variables) and `return` defines the output. You can read more on this from the PHP manual - http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php

Comment: Hmm, I partly understand what your saying.

Answer (score 3):

If I'm reading this right, just add  a return to the function.  So:

```
function char_replace($string){
  $string= str_ireplace("Snippet:", "", $string);
  // First, replace UTF-8 characters.
  $string= str_replace(
  array("\xe2\x80\x98", "\xe2\x80\x99", "\xe2\x80\x9c", "\xe2\x80\x9d", "\xe2\x80\x93", "\xe2\x80\x94", "\xe2\x80\xa6"),
  array("'", "'", '"', '"', '-', '--', '...'),
  $string);
  // Next, replace their Windows-1252 equivalents.
  $string= str_replace(
  array(chr(145), chr(146), chr(147), chr(148), chr(150), chr(151), chr(133)),
  array("'", "'", '"', '"', '-', '--', '...'),
  $string);

  return $string;
}
```

This will allow you to pass any string to the function and get the modified string back.

Answer (score 1):

Do you just want to add return statement to your function:

```
function char_replace($line1){
    $line1= str_ireplace("Snippet:", "", $line1);
    // First, replace UTF-8 characters.
    $line1= str_replace(
    array("\xe2\x80\x98", "\xe2\x80\x99", "\xe2\x80\x9c", "\xe2\x80\x9d", "\xe2\x80\x93", "\xe2\x80\x94", "\xe2\x80\xa6"),
    array("'", "'", '"', '"', '-', '--', '...'),
    $line1);
    // Next, replace their Windows-1252 equivalents.
    $line1= str_replace(
    array(chr(145), chr(146), chr(147), chr(148), chr(150), chr(151), chr(133)),
    array("'", "'", '"', '"', '-', '--', '...'),
    $line1);
    return $line1;
}
```